# calling two functions with callbacks

Tags: c, callback

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef void (*tstart)(void);
typedef void (*tstop)(void);
static tstart cbstart = NULL;
static tstart cbstop = NULL;

void init(tstart st,tstop stp)
{
      printf("in_init_func\n");
    sleep(5);
      cbstart = st;

    sleep(5);
      cbstop =  stp;
}

void start()
{
      printf("in_start_func\n");
}

void stop()
{
      printf("in_stop_func\n");
}

int main()
{
      init(start,stop);
}
```

**I have been trying to call two functions from one function with callbacks** 
as a result, I am getting below result.

*$ ./a.exe*
*in_init_func*

Comment: They are never called anywhere

Comment: You are not calling those functions, use `cbstart(); cbstop();` after the `init` line in `main`

Comment: All you're doing is assigning some function pointers to some global variables, after sleeping for a bit.  It's doing exactly what it should do:  nothing.

Comment: thnx i got that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, you are just assigning the address of function `start()` and `stop()` to their respective callbacks `cbstart` and `cbstop` in `init()` function but not using them to invoke the respective function.

Moreover, You don't need to pass the address of function `start()` and `stop()` to `init()` function. Since `start()` and `stop()` functions definition is visible in this translation unit, you just need to declare them before `init()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*tstart)(void);
typedef void (*tstop)(void);
static tstart cbstart = NULL;
static tstop cbstop = NULL;

void start();
void stop();

void init()
{
        printf("in_init_func\n");
        cbstart = start;
        cbstop =  stop;
}

void start()
{
      printf("in_start_func\n");
}

void stop()
{
      printf("in_stop_func\n");
}

int main()
{
        init();
        if (cbstart)
                cbstart();
        if (cbstop)
                cbstop();
        return 0;
}
```

After `init()`, when dereferenced, `cbstart` can be used to invoke function `start()` and `cbstop` can be used to invoke function `cbstop`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke those functions. Change `init()` to

```
void init(tstart st,tstop stp)
{
    printf("in_init_func\n");
    sleep(5);
    st();

    sleep(5);
    stp();
}
```

You can also remove `cbstart` and `cbstop` declarations, unless they are going to be used somewhere else.